# Why does not the ambient light work in this example?

Tags: three.js

In the following example, the ambient light is not working (everything is black). Why is this happening? And how do I fix it? 
If I put spot light, it works, so it must be something wrong with the ambient light, but I followed the docs ... =:O

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

            material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
                color: 0x0c79bf,
                    roughness: 0.71,
                    metalness: 1,
                    normalScale: new THREE.Vector2( 1, - 1 ), // why does the normal map require negation in this case?
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                } );


            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            var alight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040);
            scene.add( alight );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                cube.rotation.x += 0.01;                
                cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ambient light in three.js is a simple model of indirect light which is reflected by the material diffusely.

In your example, you have set the material `metalness` property to 1; that is, you are modeling a pure metal. Pure metals do not reflect light diffusely -- they only reflect light specularly.

When using `MeshStandardMaterial`, you should always specify an environment map (`material.envMap`) so your metallic materials have something to reflect.

three.js r.89

Comment: wow, what a discovery. I was modeling a metal not existent in nature , a pure metal. It was enough to set `metalness` to 0.99 and ambient light to 40 to see the light reflected. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem was actually that my aoMap didn't work on a metalic surface, I could solve it thanks to this answer and your other answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103784/ambient-occlusion-not-showing-in-three-js