# Ambient occlusion not showing in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm using the `MeshStandardMaterial` in three.js and when I create and apply the material, all maps work fine except for the `aoMap`, which has no effect on the model. I suspect this is because I don't have a 2nd set of UVs (my UV unwrapping is done through Blender and I don't manually apply any UV at all in three.js), as the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial) says:

> The red channel of this texture is used as the ambient occlusion map.
>   Default is null. ***The aoMap requires a second set of UVs***, and
>   consequently will ignore the repeat and offset Texture properties.

I've tried using the below code to solve this:

```
var geometry = mesh.geometry;
geometry.addAttribute( 'uv2', new THREE.BufferAttribute( geometry.attributes.uv.array, 2 ) );
```

but had no luck. How do I copy my UV map to the `uv2` property, or wherever it is needed to make ambient occlusion work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `aoMap` is an *ambient occlusion map*, and like its name says, it occludes ambient light. That is all it occludes.

There are currently three sources of ambient (or indirect) light in three.js: `AmbientLight`, `HemiSphereLight`, and `LightMap`.

So the `aoMap` occludes those three sources. It does not occlude direct light sources. Direct light sources include `DirectionalLight`, `SpotLight`, `PointLight`, and `AreaLight`.

three.js r.95

Comment: This is actually worth pointing out. THank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of lighting are you using? I recreated your situation, and it works as expected. The things to look out for is that aoMap shows up with THREE.AmbientLight, but not with THREE.Spotlight. It also works if you use an [envMap on your MeshStandardMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.envMap)

[image]

Comment: You are correct that with `MeshStandardMaterial` and `MeshPhysicalMaterial`, the specular reflection modeled by the `envMap` will be attenuated by the `aoMap`. This is not actually physically-correct, but was added to reduce reflections from crevices in shiny surfaces. Consider it a reasonable compromise.